# R Sum duplicated rows in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a two data frames like this

```
dat1 = data.frame("name" = c("Peter", "Tom", "Peter", "Peter", "Tom"), "adress" = c("str1", "str2", "str1", "str2", "str3"), "product" = c("prod1", "prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod2"), "val" = c(1,2,3,4,5))
dat2 = data.frame("name" = c("Tom", "Tom", "Peter", "Peter"), "adress" = c("str2", "str3", "str1", "str2"))
```

What I would like to do, is to sum for each row of 'dat2' all values of column 'val' in 'dat1' which match the values in columns 'name' and 'adress'.
Additionally I would only like to sum the values in 'dat1' if 'prod' is in a vector, e.g. `%in% c("prod1", "prod2")`

I have no idea how to this, except fpr looping through every row of 'dat2' and creating a subset data frame of 'dat1' in which I can sum the column 'val'. But my data frame is very big, so I guess that´s no good idea.

This is my desired output:

```
result = data.frame("name" = c("Tom", "Tom", "Peter", "Peter"), "adress" = c("str2", "str3", "str1", "str2"), val = c(2,5,4,NA))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be first merging the `data.frame`s and then perfom the actions needed using the `data.table` library:

```
library(data.table)

tmp <- as.data.table(merge(dat1,dat2,by=c("name","adress")))
tmp[product%in%c("prod1","prod2"),total:=sum(val),by=c("name","adress")]
tmp[,c("product","val"):=NULL]
tmp <- unique(tmp)


> tmp
    name adress total
1: Peter   str1     4
2: Peter   str2    NA
3:   Tom   str2     2
4:   Tom   str3     5
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). We can summarize the value in `dat1` and then perform a join to `dat2`. `dat3` is the final result.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create a vector
vec <- c("prod1", "prod2")

# Summarize in dat1
dat1_2 <- dat1 %>%
  filter(product %in% vec) %>%
  group_by(name, adress) %>%
  summarize(val = sum(val)) %>%
  ungroup()

# Join dat2 and dat1_2
dat3 <- dat2 %>% left_join(dat1_2, by = c("name", "adress")) 
dat3
#    name adress val
# 1   Tom   str2   2
# 2   Tom   str3   5
# 3 Peter   str1   4
# 4 Peter   str2  NA
```